# Calling js function from erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have an erb file that is creating a table. Something like this:

```
<td>Option 1</td>
<td>Option 2</td>
```

I have a javascript function called Foo() placed inside the application.js

Now I want the td header to show somehthing like this:

Option 1 Foo()

I tried doing it this way:

```
<td>Option 1 <script type="text/javascript">Foo()</script></td>
```

And it didn't work. Also tried this and it didn't work as well:

```
<td>Disbursement initiation date <%= javascript_tag "Foo()" %></td>
```

Any advice on how to do it?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way by writing your function in `document.load` jquery function.

```
<td>
 Option 1<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).load(function(){
         Foo();
         });
         </script>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take another approach; instead of trying to call the value inline, use a script to populate the values after the page have loaded, you can either add this script to the end of your page or include it in your application.js:

```
$(document).read(function() {
  $('#my_table_id td').each(function(index, col) {
    $(col).append(Foo());
  });
});
```

This way your html is clean after it has been processed and your code is unobtrusive.